# How to find a first td in a tr using tr class name in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In my application I have a table with more than 7 tr and 3 td in each. For a particular media i want to change one of my td's colspan. For that i add a class name to particular tr now using tht class name of tr i want to find first and last child of that tr. How to do this? **With out using** any script(jquery/java). I want to do this using only css.

```
 <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border- collapse: collapse; width:100%; table-layout:fixed;">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>some content</td>
    <td>some content</td>
    <td>some content</td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>some content</td>
    <td>some content</td>
    <td>some content</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>some content</td>
    <td>some content</td>
    <td>some content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="media">
    <td>some content</td>
    <td>some content</td>
    <td>some content</td>
     </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
```

Comment: Here You can see the Output. ** http://jsfiddle.net/HardRocks/x05bcust/ **

Comment: Wow, seven answers and more than half of them got it wrong. This is a duplicate, but I'm almost tempted to post an answer myself just to explain why half of the others were wrong, even if it has nothing to do with the question at hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do something like below.

```css
.media td:first-of-type {
  background: red;
  }

.media td:last-of-type {
  background: green;
  }
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border- collapse: collapse; width:100%; table-layout:fixed;">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>some content</td>
    <td>some content</td>
    <td>some content</td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>some content</td>
    <td>some content</td>
    <td>some content</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>some content</td>
    <td>some content</td>
    <td>some content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="media">
    <td>some content</td>
    <td>some content</td>
    <td>some content</td>
     </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
```

**Note:** If they are going to be styled the same, you can add them together as shown below.

```
 .media td:last-of-type, .media td:first-of-type {
      background: green;
      }
```

Comment: You still need to repeat the `.media` portion after the comma.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
.media td:first-child,.media td:last-child{
        background-color: red;
    }
```

If you want choose a certain td in `.media`, you can use

```
//n is the td you want select. n starts from 1
.media td:nth-child(n) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For pure javascript code.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("class-name").childNodes[0]; //first element

document.getElementsByClassName("class-name").childNodes[2]; //last element
```

For CSS:

.media is class for a particular tr. If you are using different classes for tr then you can reuse below code with different class name.

```
  .media td:first-child{
background-color:red;
}

.media td:last-child{
background-color:red;
}
```

More enhancement, if you are using different class names like media-1, media-2 for different TRs:

```
tr[class^="media-"] td:first-child{
background-color:red;
}

tr[class^="media-"] td:last-child{
background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: OP is not looking for JS solution.

Comment: I apologize. Didn't see that. Will post CSS solution.

Comment: Still incorrect - your class selector is misplaced.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is....

```
table .media:first-child,
.media:last-child{
    background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
table tr.media td:first-child{}

table tr.media td:last-child{}
```